# Is it good practice to make environment variables global?

Tags: php

I have some modular ( object and classes ) JavaScript and PHP.  I keep getting advice to get rid of global variables..."they are bad"...I guess because they cause dependencies.

However where should I put environment variables - the best example being path information.

Here is a quintessential example.

The UploadFile class below needs

```
const     PICTURES = '../pictures/';
```

particularly in this spot ( no need to read entire class )

```
$this->path_medium = UploadedFile::PICTURES . "$this->sessionId.jpg";
$this->path_small = UploadedFile::PICTURES . "$this->sessionId-1.jpg";
```

to no where to upload files to.  I would prefer to put it in a GlobalClass and access it from there.  It makes sense as other code will need to know where pictures go, and I will have only one location to make updates.

Are having environment variables O.K to have as globals so they can be accessed from multiple modules yet edited in only one place.

```
<?php

/**
 *      Module  :       Model
 *      Name    :       UploadFile
 *      Input   :       File Information
 *      Output  :       Resized Files in .jpg format
 *      Notes   :

 resizeMove() - resizes the picture to $maxMedium and $maxSmall and moves the file to a permanent location.  
 makeDimensions() - calculates the dimensions of the new images so that there is not distortion if possible.
 getImage() - creates a php image for manipulation.
 updateSessionAndDb - updates the mysql table - move out.

 */

    class UploadedFile
    {
    const     PICTURES = '../pictures/';

    private  $originalWidth, 
             $originalHeight, 
             $newWidth, 
             $newHeight, 
             $maxMedium = 50,
             $maxSmall = 20;

    private  $src = NULL;

    private 
             $fileType,
             $fileName,
             $sessionId,
             $path_medium,
             $path_small;

    function __construct($fileType, $fileName)
    {
        $this->sessionId = Session::get('id');
        $this->path_medium = UploadedFile::PICTURES . "$this->sessionId.jpg";
        $this->path_small = UploadedFile::PICTURES . "$this->sessionId-1.jpg";
        $this->fileType = $fileType;
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
    }

    public function createImages()
    {
        if(move_uploaded_file($this->fileName, $this->path_medium))
        {
            if($this->getImage($this->path_medium))
            {
                list($this->originalWidth,$this->originalHeight)=getimagesize($this->path_medium);
                $this->resizeMove($this->maxMedium,$this->path_medium);
                $this->resizeMove($this->maxSmall,$this->path_small);
                imagedestroy($this->src);
            }
        }
    }

    private function resizeMove($max, $path)
    {
        $this->makeDimensions($max);
        $image_true_color = imagecreatetruecolor($this->newWidth, $this->newHeight);
        imagecopyresampled($image_true_color, $this->src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $this->newWidth, $this->newHeight, $this->
        originalWidth, $this->originalHeight);
        imagejpeg($image_true_color, $path);
        imagedestroy($image_true_color);
    }

    private function makeDimensions($max)
    {
        $this->newWidth=$this->originalWidth; 
        $this->newHeight=$this->originalHeight;
        if(($this->originalWidth > $this->originalHeight) && ($this->originalWidth > $max))
        {
            $this->newWidth = $max;
            $this->newHeight = ($max / $this->originalWidth) * $this->originalHeight;
        }
        elseif($this->originalHeight > $this->originalWidth && $this->originalHeight > $max)
        {
            $this->newHeight = $max;
            $this->newWidth = ($max / $this->originalHeight) * $this->originalWidth;
        } 
        elseif ($this->originalWidth > $max)
        {
            $this->newWidth = $this->newHeight = $max;
        }
    }

    private function getImage($path)
    {
        $type_creators = array( 
            'image/gif' => 'imagecreatefromgif', 
            'image/pjpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg', 
            'image/jpeg' => 'imagecreatefromjpeg', 
            'image/png' => 'imagecreatefrompng'); 
        if(array_key_exists($this->fileType, $type_creators)) 
        { 
            $this->src = $type_creators[$this->fileType]($path); 
            return true; 
        }
    return false; 
    }
}
```

**Object Maker Example**

```
class ObjectMaker
{
    public function makeSignUp()
    {
        $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        $TextObject = new Text();
        $MessageObject = new Message();

        $SignUpObject = new ControlSignUp();        
        $SignUpObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject);
        return $SignUpObject;
    }
```

**Object Maker Example Revised**

```
    class ObjectMaker
    {
        public function makeSignUp()
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
            $TextObject = new Text();
            $MessageObject = new Message();

            return new ControlSignUp( $DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject );        
        }
```

**Notes:**

I have may classes similar to SignUp so I can use inheritance to reduce redundancy of object creation by using an ObjectMaker Class - Back to the original problem - I can include injection of Globals not just Objects in this "pattern".

Comment: The trouble with a global variable is that is makes your class dependent on its existence, thus breaking the class by default. This is important if it is a library class, but less so if it is dedicated to your app - but it is always good to aim for.

Comment: Also, if it is a `const` or a `define` then it cannot be changed during the course of execution (this happens more often than one might think, even for your example - such as in unit testing). The most elegant solution is to employ the _dependency injection_ pattern, though sometimes the cost of setting that up outweighs the benefit of reducing dependencies.

Comment: True...if I set up a Global Class with Private members and access via getter..I could then use dependency injection to inject that class....best practice vs. lots more work...hmmmm

Comment: If the only configuration item for `UploadedFile` is the root path, I'd add `$picturesRoot` to the constructor, or maybe add a setter `setPicturesRoot($picturesRoot)` to the class. That way this class doesn't need to worry about accepting application-specific config objects - your controller(s) can do that stuff.

Comment: @halfr - agreed, so does hakre below.

Comment: will likely place that code in ObjectMaker and replace my current method...this will reduce the redundant calls to similar objects...added this to question

Comment: I have may classes similar to SignUp so I can use inheritance to reduce redundancy of object creation by using an ObjectMaker Class - Back to the original problem - I can include injection of Globals not just Objects in this "pattern".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make your class re-useable, you should not hardcode stuff in there, but inject it instead. Like the session id and the base directory for the images. Add those as parameters to your constructor:

```
function __construct($fileType, $fileName, $sessionId, $prefixPictures)
{
    $this->fileType = $fileType;
    $this->fileName = $fileName;
    $this->sessionId = $sessionId;
    $this->prefixPictures = $prefixPictures;

    $this->path_medium = $prefixPictures . $this->sessionId . ".jpg";
    $this->path_small = $prefixPictures . $this->sessionId . "-1.jpg";
}
```

Additionally you should create a class of it's own, one to resize a picture and one to do the size calculations. Actually such classes already exist, so you just need to include some file, and do the resize (e.g. with [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: I've seen this a lot...dependency injection through the constructor....this is bit easier than creating an ObjectMaker ( thw way I currently do it ) that handles DI.

Comment: Actually I need to update that file to go through the constructor...a bit more concise.

Comment: Good spot on the session thing, another dependency. I might be inclined to use more setters however - whilst the object needs all of these variables, I'm presently somewhat in agreement with the _Clean Code_ maxim that more than three parameters is getting unwieldy. But, +1 all the same.

Comment: @halfer: As written, that class does too much anyway, `$fileType` and `$fileName` look redundant, the meaning is actually only to identify an image.

Comment: @TheAllFoo What you are doing is either a DI container or an abstract factory. It is important to note that DI (dependency injection) is useful in most projects _without_ a DI container or an abstract factory.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. You could make a path getter that outputs a property of a paths class ( i.e. `Paths::pictures` )

Then again, at that level its kind of up to the developer.

I think for organization's sake, its good to stick them all in a namespace and call them that way. It helps when new devs come along

Comment: that way I could update them in one location, make them private, yet access anywhere..this sounds like best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Constants are not as bad as global variables and using it for path is by far the most common method to overcome the awkwardness of PHP not having a 'true' root path variable (you can have it based on current script by using **DIR**, but not based on script that called current script).

The main reason why globals are bad are not because they are globals but because they can be changed anywhere in the script. In fact, this is one of my main gripes about PHP - $_SERVER variables can be changed during script run and I wish they were constants.

Constants can only be defined and used and editing them will not be possible. As long as you document the existence of globals well enough then managing them is no more difficult than managing any other PHP environment variable.

As long as you don't go all crazy with them it is fine. Remember that environment always plays a role when it comes to testing and as long as you are aware of the environment and can easily mock it, then it does not cause more problems to testing.

Comment: The biggest issue with globals (including constants) is that they create a list of dependencies that are difficult to control. If you build a class that accepts injected settings, you can easily test that class in isolation. Contrast that with a class that relies on globals and/or constants (class constants are better, but do note that they are of limited use when it comes to configuration) which can't easily be injected but have to be setup before running a test.

Comment: This is exactly what I said wilmoore. But since software is already dependent on environment (PHP versions introduce certain _SERVER variables that are not available on other versions, also Apache and Nginx introduce different variables) that if you have a framework or a larger system then you would depend on environment anyway (and use a mockup). Introducing one more global for true root path is perfectly fine and as long as its documented, it causes no more trouble to testing since a well built OOP class needs to test for existence of variables and constants before use anyway. And always.

Comment: To be clear...we are saying "similar" things, but not "exactly" the same thing. My clarification above implied (but I should have noted explicitly) the context of a module (rather than an application). Your rebuttal argues for constants such as ROOT_PATH which would be calculated early on in the bootstrap process. This is good, but this is at the application level and should be documented in an application level README or something similar. At the end of the day, minimizing the number of global constants is good. There is no hard limit...play it by ear but be careful :)

Comment: Yes, we seem to be talking about the same thing and not really disagreeing there :)